# multi-line statement in Netezza Stored Procedure using Strings

Tags: sql, netezza

I am creating a stored procedure so I can use parameters in a select statement.  using a REFTABLE, I want to return the REFTABLE as a response to the STORED PROCEDURE.

Using this as an example:

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || REFTABLENAME ||' SELECT * FROM STUD_REC';
```

my problem is when single-quotes and double-quotes used in the statement.  This SQL Statement is not mine.

The statement looks like this:

```
SELECT 'THIS IS MY TEXT' as "TEXT LINE"
```

the end result I'm looking for loks like this:

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || REFTABLENAME ||' SELECT 'THIS IS MY TEXT' as "TEXT LINE"';
```

Naturally, I know I can't use single-quotes inside when the main string is single quoted.  I'm trying to avoid Escaping quotes as it will royally confuse the originator of the select statement.

In python, a triple quote(''') represents a block string.  The block string allows for single quotes and double quotes in the block.  Is there one in Netezza I can use?

Thanks

Update #1.  While this is a small SQL statement, the actual one is large with multiple lines.  How does this affect my construction?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you need to double up on the single quotes for them to appear in a string:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || REFTABLENAME || ' SELECT ''THIS IS MY TEXT'' as "TEXT LINE"';
```

Comment: ok.  just because I didn't challenge this enough...sorry.  what if the original query is multi-lined.  Does that matter?

Comment: @arcee123 . . . It doesn't change how you insert single quotes into a string (by doubling them).